# KSQLDB - how to add message with key to Kafka topic with using serializer JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm trying to add message with key to Kafka topic (running locally on DOCKER). I don't know why, JSON serializer works for value but not for key.

Creating the topic and stream in KSQLDB CLI using the command:
`CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS users_stream (id VARCHAR KEY, employeeId BIGINT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users_topic', KEY_FORMAT='JSON', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=2);`

After 'SHOW STREAMS;' command:
[Show streams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxqsz.png)

Add message by kafka-console-producer using command:
`docker-compose exec broker kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:29092 --property parse.key=true --property key.separator="&" --property key.serializer=custom.class.serialization.JsonSerializer --property value.serializer=custom.class.serialization.JsonSerializer --topic users_topic`

And add message:
`{"id":"COLE888"}&{"employeeId":"1470258"}`

After 'SELECT * FROM user_stream;' column 'id' contains JSON String.
[select * from streams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBB9t.png)

What should I change to get only value at column "ID" which is the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one column, then select it

```
SELECT id FROM users_stream
```

When you say "at, or *within*, a column", you have just a varchar, so it is not "a column". If that's your intention, use `STRUCT` types.

If you're asking how to unwrap the data, then you will either need to use json extraction functions, or just don't produce JSON data as your key.